# Creating an instance of UserManager<T> in tests

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I'm very new to the concept of mocking and I struggle with injecting/mocking an `UserManager<T>` to my tests

I need to use `await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);`

I've found this one

```
public static UserManager<TUser> TestUserManager<TUser>(IUserStore<TUser> store = null) where TUser : class
{
    store = store ?? new Mock<IUserStore<TUser>>().Object;
    var options = new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>();
    var idOptions = new IdentityOptions();
    idOptions.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
    options.Setup(o => o.Value).Returns(idOptions);
    var userValidators = new List<IUserValidator<TUser>>();
    var validator = new Mock<IUserValidator<TUser>>();
    userValidators.Add(validator.Object);
    var pwdValidators = new List<PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
    pwdValidators.Add(new PasswordValidator<TUser>());
    var userManager = new UserManager<TUser>(store, options.Object, new PasswordHasher<TUser>(),
        userValidators, pwdValidators, new UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer(),
        new IdentityErrorDescriber(), null,
        new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<TUser>>>().Object);
    validator.Setup(v => v.ValidateAsync(userManager, It.IsAny<TUser>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success)).Verifiable();

    return userManager;
}
```

But this throws

> System.NotSupportedException : Store does not implement IUserPasswordStore.

How can I create an working `UserManager<T>` instance in tests?

I'm using Xunit

Comment: Can you post a bit more code ? Like the definition of IUserStore<TUser>, and IUserPasswordStore ?

Comment: Those interfaces come from ``Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserstore-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserpasswordstore-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all revise about your approach, I've read some different papers that people says you don't need to test a library and a tool that has been already tested.
But sometimes we need to mock `UserManager` to inject our services and resolve these dependencies.
`UserManager` can be mocked really simple, but error messages like that are not well explained.
We must mock the `UserStore` first and give it to `UserManager`, to mock UserStore you can create a class `MockUserStore` which derives `IUserStore` and `IUserPasswordStore` :

```
public class MockUserStore : IUserStore<TUser>, IUserPasswordStore<TUser>
```

This mock class must implement some methods of IUserPasswordStore, otherwise you catch that error message!

```
public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user, string passwordHash,
     CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.FromResult<string>(user.PasswordHash);
}

public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.FromResult<bool>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PasswordHash));
}
```

You can also use a class to mock `UserManager` and override its methods with mocked methods:

```
public class MockUserManager : UserManager<TUser>
{
    public MockUserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
     IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators,
      IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
       IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }

    public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
```

after all you can mock the `UserManager` with passing mocked `UserStore`:

```
    var userStore = new MockUserStore();
    var userManager = new MockUserManager(userStore,
                        new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                        new Mock<IPasswordHasher<AppUser>>().Object,
                        new IUserValidator<TUser>[0],
                        new IPasswordValidator<TUser>[0],
                        new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                        new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                        new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                        new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<TUser>>>().Object);
    return userManager;
```